# Spark Hadoop JAR throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Cloneable

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I build a jar file foo.jar using the following command on my local machine and run it, it works fine.

```
mvn -f foo/pom.xml clean package -DskipTests
```

However, when I upload the same jar to a remote machine and try to run it, I get this error with the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Cloneable
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Cloneable
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 16 more
```

I am unable to understand what the root cause of this problem is.

P.S. My pom contains:

```
 <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <cascadingVersion>3.0.4</cascadingVersion>
    <hadoopVersion>2.9.0</hadoopVersion>        
    <junit.version>4.7</junit.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
    <mysql-connector.version>8.0.11</mysql-connector.version>
    <jetty.version>9.3.7.v20160115</jetty.version>
    <jackson.version>2.9.8</jackson.version>
    <lucene.version>4.6.0</lucene.version>
    <scala.version>2.11.8</scala.version>
    <scala.compat.version>2.11</scala.compat.version>
    <kafka.version>2.1.0</kafka.version>
    <jacoco.version>0.7.7.201606060606</jacoco.version>
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPaths>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    <autosuggest.commons.version>1.0.29</autosuggest.commons.version>
    <powermockito.version>1.6.2</powermockito.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: How are you running that jar locally and on the remote machine?

Comment: The command you've provided doesn't run the code. Also unclear if you're using a shaded JAR or what version of Scala (or Spark) the machine you've deployed the code to runs